# find the exact line and copy it - windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, find

my input file is

abcd 145
abcd 148
abcd 153
abcd 523
abcd 563

I'd like to write a batch file to find the `n`th line and each `k` line thereafter in an input text file (ie. line `n` then line `n+k`, `n+2k` and so on) and copy it to another txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 SET "printme=Y"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21027851.txt) DO (
  IF DEFINED printme (ECHO %%a&SET "printme=") ELSE (SET printme=Y)

 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Input in file `q21027851.txt` output to `newfile.txt`

Setting `printme` to nothing originally would print the even-numbered lines instead.

---

Given revised specification (which I'll include in the question by editing it)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET firstline=1
SET skipby=5
(
 SET /a skipme=firstline-1
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21027851.txt) DO (
  IF !skipme!==0 SET /a skipme=%skipby%&ECHO %%a
  SET /a skipme-=1   
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Cool - 'tis what it's all about. Now if you'd care to click the appropriate emty tick to the left of the response, that will mark the response as `accepted` and award us both some `rep`utation points.

Answer (score 0):

```
:PRINTFILE
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET X=0
FOR /F "skip=%2 tokens=*" %%I IN (%1) DO (
        SET /A X=1-!X!
        IF "!X!"=="1" ECHO %%I
        )
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

You must invoke the code as

```
CALL :PRINTFILE INPUT.TXT 1 > OUTPUT.TXT
```

Output will start at line 1 (in the above case) and will emit line 3, 5 ... and so on from INPUT.TXT and will store the ouput to OUTPUT.TXT

Comment: hey thx for reply, but id like to skip first 4 line and then copy 1-6-12-18 ... . to do that, i need to write "skip =%4 and x=!x!+5 in printfile" ??

Comment: sorry my mistake . it needs to be copied 1st - 6th - 11th and so on after skippin first 4 line

Answer (score 0):

use a good file parsing tool such `awk`

```
C:\>awk "NR%2!=0{print}" myFile.txt
abcd 145
abcd 153
abcd 563
```

you can download `awk` [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cja5mvymvinmfco/mHw6J4I1Kd) or [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

Comment: id like to skip first 4 line and copyin 1st - 6th - 11th and so on. (n to n+5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
:PRINTFILE
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET X=0
FOR /F "skip=%2 tokens=*" %%I IN (%1) DO (
        SET /A R=!X!%%%3
        IF "!R!"=="0" ECHO.%%I
        SET /A X+=1
        )
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

Use the following to invoke this code

```
CALL :PRINTFILE INPUT.TXT 4 5 > OUTPUT.TXT
```

Where 4 is the number of lines to skip at the beginning of the file and 5 is the step i.e  it will print Line 4, Line 4+5, Line 4+5+5 and so on..

NOTE: If your text file has chars like ! or ^ it needs escaping :(

(Couldn't add it as comment due to reputation problems :-p)